# How to select an item from the combox menu in ibm rational functional tester

Tags: java, combobox, rft

I am trying to select a text item from the text combobox menu.
Its a `DHTM` text combobox and i am using `RFT 8.1.1.3`.
The properties of the combobox is `.class=Html.INPUT.text` and its not showing any other unique property. there is no index and length property for the dropdown values.
so how do i select the values of the drop down menu.

Answer (score 1):

If it is actually a combobox it should not have the .class property as  *Html.INPUT.text*

Is there a Html.INPUT.select in the DOM hierarchy somewhere ?

Looking at the DOM you can try to find the actual hierarchy of the elements and then using RFT's find() API , you can try to find the control you are looking for and calling some setProperty() on it to select a particular element.

It would help if you could point to some page where such combobox exists so we understand the control better.